# Quadratic program with equality and inequality constraints

Tags: quadratic-programming

I am trying to get the standard form of a quadratic program. The general form is as follows

[image: general form]

I don't understand how to get the matrix $a$ (for the coefficients  of the inequality constraints) of the following specific problem:

[image]

Please can anyone tell me how to write the matrix $a$ and matrix $b$ this problem(as shown in the general form) in order to get the standard form of this quadratic problem?

Comment: How does look the equation in general where A is involved?

Comment: hi, thanks for mentioning. Yes now I have added the general form

Comment: $a$ is a vector, not a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the representation of the picture you can write each constraint as a product of two vectors. For instance the first inequality:

$$ 3x_1+4x_2-2x_3= \left(\begin{array}{} 3 & 4 & -2  \end{array}\right)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}{} x_1  \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \end{pmatrix}\leq 10$$

But if you want to use one *coefficient matrix* $A$ for all equations we have to add slack variables (+$s_i$) and surplus variables ($-s_i$), since all constraints have to be equations.

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{} 3&4&-2&1&0&0&0&0  \\ -3&2&1&0&-1&0&0&0 \\ 2&3&4&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}}_{A}\cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{} x_1  \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ s_1 \\ s_2\\ s_3\\ s_2\\ s_5 \end{pmatrix}}_{x}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{}10 \\ 2 \\ 5  \\ 5\\  5 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}}_{b}$$

The second constraint is $-3x_1+2x_2+x_3-s_2=2$. You just have to know how to multiply a matrix by a vector.

And finally the non-negativity condition: $x_i,s_i\geq 0$

Comment: thank you so much bro

Comment: @Rohail You´re welcome.